# execute url in php file to send sms from web server

Tags: php

THIS code is properly working on offline i.e. localhost bt i also want to execute this on web server...bt is not working on server....so anyone please tell me to execute the url on server for sms sending...

```html
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/* Here is my api url*/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Not working? Can you give us any error or traces? I personnaly can't read in mind.

Comment: no...it display blank page on browser

Comment: Try adding CURLOPT_USERAGENT to options but firstly check if cURL is enabled

Comment: yeah curl is enable

Comment: What does `curl_exec($ch)` return? If it returns `FALSE`, check what `curl_error($ch)` says.

Comment: Try using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Maybe there are some hidden errors / warnings, that would help You figure out, what's wrong.